# javascript-es6: unable to destructure an array of objects. UNEXPECTED TOKEN ERROR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring, react-table

I have an array of objects and I am trying to destructure it so that I can directly use the property names in `react-table`'s column's `accessor` property.

This is the raw JSON which is actually being fetched via an API call.

Not sure, where I am going wrong though.

Comment: Your `let [` (or `const [`) is inside the body of a class, so it's not valid place to declare a *variable*.

Comment: @VLAZ right. ok. can you help me with a working example of sorts? maybe edit my `codeSandbox` thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take sites in your state in the handleGetmeasurementsDataInfo() this way :

```
handleGetmeasurementsDataInfo = async function() {
await axios

  .get("https://run.mocky.io/v3/7c15d8c2-e946-40f4-a1b9-a9a53436b388")
  .then(response => {
    // handle success
    console.log("measurement data:", response.data);
    const sites = response.data.map(e => e.sites);
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      measurementsData: response.data,
      sites: sites
    });
    console.log("Sites: ", this.state.sites);
  })
  [...]
```

You can then access it from your state.

[Codebox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-monad-i6ig0?file=/src/DataViewTable.js)

Comment: thanks. any suggestions for the table? how do I get them in a different/new row each time?

Comment: I think an answer validition would be appreciated if the answer meet your expectations